# Get article from thousands of categories

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP and MySQL, to get articles from *5* categories (`id`: *1*,*2*,*3*,*4*,*5*), I use this MySQL query:

```
select * from `articles` where `category` in(1,2,3,4,5)
```

It's ok with *5* categories, but how about *1,000* categories ? Can you give me some idea to solve this problem, thank you very much.

Note: the problem I want to tell is not non-working query, it is very slow to process, are there some ways to speed it up ?

Comment: add a subquery, clearly you want to get articles form a specific set of categories having some properties: `select * from 'articles' where 'category' in (select category.id from categories where visitors> 100)`

Comment: Hmmm . . . `IN` still works.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem I want to tell is not not-working query, it is very slow to process, are there some ways to speed it up ?

Comment: Make sure the Category field has an index in your database

Comment: Do we have an index in the column `category`?

Comment: if you have a lot of products and you are bringing everything ( * ) from products from a 1000 categories you can't expect a good performance. 
Each row of your articles will be compared to each row of your categories)
If you want all products, don't filter by category.

Comment: @MaK I already asked that

Comment: @JulioSoares I disagree. You should be able to have better performance as long as it's done right.

Comment: Thank you @CodeGodie , MaK  and Julio very much, I have an index in category column. I am sorry, because of my bad english so I don't know which words can explain what I want. Finally, I want to optimize the query so It can work more faster than.

Comment: @LyQuiChung Can you share the table structure, along with some sample data & what exactly you need as output? That'll help.

Comment: No prob and like @MaK said, provide as much info as possible

Comment: @Mak, CodeGodie: Hi, I would like to create a news project which have a future similar with social-network, so user can follow categories they like. I am still thinking about this project, such as how to optimize when the number of users is very big. I have not writen something yet, but the articles table may be simple like this: article_table (Column: id,name,image,content,category).

Comment: @LyQuiChung, do you even have a table on which you tested the said query or are you assuming it will be slow?

Comment: @ndn, haha, you make me so embarrassed, I am really assuming :D If the query is not slow with the quantity of 1,000 categories, it must slow with more quantity than(About 9k or 10k categories)

Comment: @LyQuiChung Well there are ways to speed up performance of a query. Whatever I got from your description is that you have a customer table & a categories table. Now there's anoter table customer_catgories which is a many-many relationship & is for storing the categories that customer liked.

So given proper indexing & proper query, I think mysql has enough ammunition in it's disposal to handle the query & return desired response in as fast way as possible.

Comment: Hi @Mak, thank you very much, all of you are so friendly and enthusiastic :D

Comment: @LyQuiChung, the query shouldn't be slow, even for 10k categories. Even then, there are things to do. You can use indexing and partitioning. Or you can rewrite the query to use joins, instead of subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to get all `articles` for `category`s starting from `1`, upto `1000`, you can use between:

```
select * from articles where category between 1 and 1000
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I want to get articles from 1,000 categories or more than, of course , the IDs are random.

Comment: @LyQuiChung, well, if they are not consecutive, the question here is how did you get those values and what is the problem with using `in` in your case?

Comment: Hi @ndn, there are no problems with the query, I just want to optimize and increase the processing speed :) Sorry, my english is not good.

Comment: @LyQuiChung, assuming you got the categories from another query, you can try to use join instead of subqueries.

Comment: Hi @ndn, I would like to create a news project which have a future similar with social-network, so user can follow categories they like. I am still thinking about this project, such as how to optimize when the number of users is very big. I have not writen something yet, but the articles table may be simple like this: article_table (Column: id,name,image,content,category).

Comment: @LyQuiChung so basically, you haven't even tried the original query, you just assumed it will be slow?

Comment: I am sorry @ndn, I really assume it will be slow, I will test soon, thank you very much friend, you are so friendly and enthusiastic :D